# Functional Search Bar to Find on the Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, search

So, I have a web page that will display files from a folder. [image: Here's what it looks like now]

As more and more files are created the table will grow and I want the search bar to have functionality and either highlight in some way or move the page to display the searched term in the center. For example, if someone types "Janet" it will bring them to "Janet". Just like control+f on a web page. I have looked a lot on this site but haven't found a question similar with an answer. If its a duplicate please let me know and thanks!

Comment: What have you tried, can't get to work, etc?

Comment: If you are just looking for how to scroll the user to the desired content, there is a JavaScript method `window.scrollTo(x,y)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo or the newer (experimental) `element.scrollIntoView()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: @ggdx I haven't tried anything yet because I simply don't know where to start. I looked around on the internet but nothing really seemed to fit the mold. if you could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for responding!

Comment: @scunliffe, The scrolling would be nice however, finding it on the page would be the more desired feature.

Comment: @Chris https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+search+my+page+javascript

Comment: I'd suggest that you place a span around each "result" that you have (e.g. each file name) and give it a special CSS class. Then when you run your search, get all spans with that class e.g. `var results = document.querySelectorAll('span.yourSpecialClass');` then iterate over them looking for your keyword(s).

Comment: Unless your search is doing something the browser isn't, why bother? Also if your list is actually large it would make sense to paginate your results and then it would be useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your search function returns an array of html elements that fit your search, you can access the first element in the array and find it's position in the DOM.

Use [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to find it's position relative to the window. Add `window.scrollX` and/or `window.scrollY` to have it's position relative to the DOM.

Then, you can use window.scrollTo(x, y) to scroll the user to that location.

It makes sense to tie this to a function that executes when you want the scrolling to happen, perhaps after the user presses enter (instead of after each character input).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found my answer at http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm though. I truly appreciate a nice response that's well thought out instead of people just disliking my question for god knows what reason